# Only fire trigger when account owner is changed in a before update trigger

Tags: apex

I have written the following trigger and it works great. This trigger basically allows you to retain the Account Team if someone forgets to check the "keep account team" checkbox. This is the code I currently have:

```
trigger AccountTriggerKeepAcctTeam on Account (before update) {
    List<AccountTeamMember> listAcc = [SELECT Id, AccountAccessLevel, AccountId, CaseAccessLevel, UserId, ContactAccessLevel, OpportunityAccessLevel, TeamMemberRole, PhotoUrl, Title FROM AccountTeamMember Where AccountId in : Trigger.new AND TeamMemberRole != 'Account Executive']; 
    system.debug('AccountTeamMember records: '+(JSON.serialize(listAcc))); 
    String str = JSON.serialize(listAcc); 
     //delete team member records if required
    AccountTriggerKeepAcctTeamHandler.retainOldTeamMemberOnOwnerChange(str); 
}

public class AccountTriggerKeepAcctTeamHandler {
    @future
    public static void retainOldTeamMemberOnOwnerChange(String str){
        system.debug('Future call '+str); 
        List<AccountTeamMember> newlistAcc = (List<AccountTeamMember>) JSON.deserialize(str,List<AccountTeamMember>.class);
        for(AccountTeamMember objAccTeamMember : newlistAcc){
            objAccTeamMember.Id= null;
        }
        system.debug('Account records to insert'+(JSON.serialize(newlistAcc)));
        Upsert newlistAcc;
    }
}
```

However, I would like to add one small addition. I only want to fire this trigger when the Account Owner is changed. This is my attempt but I am getting errors:

```
trigger AccountTriggerKeepAcctTeam on Account (before update) { 
    Account oldAcct = Trigger.oldMap.get(Trigger.new.Id); //new line added. Has errors 
    if(oldAcct.OwnerId != Trigger.new.OwnerId){ //new line added 
        List listAcc = [SELECT Id, AccountAccessLevel, AccountId, CaseAccessLevel, UserId, ContactAccessLevel, OpportunityAccessLevel, TeamMemberRole, PhotoUrl, Title FROM AccountTeamMember Where AccountId in : Trigger.new AND TeamMemberRole != 'Account Executive']; 
       system.debug('AccountTeamMember records: '+(JSON.serialize(listAcc))); 
      String str = JSON.serialize(listAcc); //delete team member records if required 
       AccountTriggerKeepAcctTeamHandler.retainOldTeamMemberOnOwnerChange(str); 
     } 
    }
```

Thank you

Attempt 2: New version of code:

```
trigger AccountTriggerKeepAcctTeam on Account (before update) {
    List<AccountTeamMember> listAcc = [SELECT Id, AccountAccessLevel, AccountId, CaseAccessLevel, UserId, ContactAccessLevel, OpportunityAccessLevel, TeamMemberRole, PhotoUrl, Title FROM AccountTeamMember Where AccountId in : Trigger.new AND TeamMemberRole != 'Account Executive']; 
    for(Account acc: Trigger.new){
        Account oldAccount = Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id);
        if(acc.OwnerId != oldAccount.OwnerId){
            system.debug('AccountTeamMember records: '+(JSON.serialize(listAcc))); 
            String str = JSON.serialize(listAcc); 
             //delete team member records if required
            AccountTriggerKeepAcctTeamHandler.retainOldTeamMemberOnOwnerChange(str);   
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `Trigger.new` and `Trigger.old` are lists so you will need to iterate first and then compare. You may want to look at the trailhead for triggers here https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro and here is a good example of how to compare old values with new values. https://www.biswajeetsamal.com/blog/compare-old-and-new-values-in-salesforce-trigger/

Comment: welcome to sfse; you should review how to write triggers in Trailhead - you are missing iterating through Trigger.new

Comment: can i compare the account owner values without using a for loop?

Comment: Hello @manjit5190 does my new version of the code/fix make sense? Will that work. Basically, I would like to retain the account team member on account only if the acct owner has changed which means the future method gets called when the owner changes. Can you please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

Second version is almost OK.

You are correctly cycling through the Accounts coming through the trigger and checking for change in owner.

Now, if change is detected, you need to collect Account IDs.

Then, after iteration - if there are no IDs collected, get out of the trigger.  Don't do AccTeamMember lookup before iterating, because it will use up a SOQL, take time, and may be completely unnecessary if there is no owner change.

If there are some IDs, then do the Lookup of AccountTeamMember, and also send data off to the future method.

You will also need to adjust the future method to process a different variable - `List<Account>`.

Sample code below, but I didn't test it, so it may have some minor bugs.

```
trigger AccountTriggerKeepAcctTeam on Account (before update) {
    Set accIds = new Set();
    
    for(Account acc : Trigger.new){
        Account oldAccount = Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id);
            if (acc.OwnerId != oldAccount.OwnerId) {
                accIds.add(acc.id);
            }            
        }
    }
    if (accIds.isEmpty()) return;  // so that you don't have to waste time on lookups and future calls if there is nothing to process
    
    List accs = [
        select id, 
        (select id, 
         AccountAccessLevel, 
         AccountId, 
         CaseAccessLevel, 
         UserId, 
         ContactAccessLevel, 
         OpportunityAccessLevel, 
         TeamMemberRole, 
         PhotoUrl, 
         Title 
         from AccountTeamMembers
         where TeamMemberRole != 'Account Executive')
        from Account 
        where id in :accIds
    ];
    
    AccountTriggerKeepAcctTeamHandler.retainOldTeamMemberOnOwnerChange(JSON.serialize(accs));
}

public class AccountTriggerKeepAcctTeamHandler {

    @future
    public static void retainOldTeamMemberOnOwnerChange(String str){
        system.debug('Future call '+str); 
        List accs = (List) JSON.deserialize(str, List.class);
        List members = new List();
        
        for (Account acc : accs) {
            for (AccountTeamMember member : acc.AccountTeamMembers) {
                member.id = null;
                members.add(member);            
            }
        }
        system.debug('Account records to insert' + (JSON.serialize(members)));
        insert members;        
    }
}
```